# How do I use Html.ActionLink to specify a route with no action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have configured a route where I can omit the action and it will use the default one, while leaving the action out of the url. Ie. `/Group/12345` rather than `/Group/Index/12345`. The route works.

Problem is I'm having trouble constructing an anchor tag using `Html.ActionLink` which will output `/Group/12345`. It only ever seems to give me `/Group/Index/12345`.

My routes are set up like this:

```
context.MapRoute(
    name: "Group",
    url: "/Group/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Group", action = "Index" },
    namespaces: new [] { "Website.Controllers" },
    constraints: new { id = @"\d+" });

context.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    namespaces: new[] { "Website.Controllers" });
```

And my attempt to build the link looks like this so far:

```
Html.ActionLink("View", "", "Group", new { id = 12345 }, new { @class = "btn btn-default" })
```

I've tried passing in both null and empty string as an `action` parameter but it still puts 'Index' in the url.

Comment: The code you have shown would not generate `/Group/Index/12345` (your adding `id` as a `htmlAttribute`, not a route value) - it needs to be `@Html.ActionLink("View", "Index", "Group", new { id = 12345 }, null)`

Comment: Sorry, in my attempt to simplify my example code I ended up leaving out the  HtmlAttributes argument to ActionLink(). Have added this back in to reflect the code I'm actually working with.

Comment: You need to replace `""` with `"Index"`

Comment: That still results in /Group/Index/12345, not /Group/12345.

Comment: What you have shown will work fine. Are you sure the route definitions you have shown are in that order, or that there are no other definitions before those that may match?

Comment: @OP Are you sure your code could run? Since the route url can't start with '/' or '~'. I think there will be an `ArgumentException` upon the first visit to the site